# How to use combination of ARG and ENV in Dockerfile to prevent unsupported modifier in substitution?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use an example from [Docker docs on ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

```
FROM ubuntu                                                                                          
                                                                                                      
ARG TEST                                                                                             
ENV TEST=${TEST:foo}                                                                                 
                                                                                                      RUN echo $TEST
```

Docker docs says:

> The variable expansion technique in this example allows you to pass arguments from the
> command line and persist them in the final image by leveraging the `ENV` instruction.

The build fails with the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
16ec32c2132b: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
 ---> 1318b700e415
Step 2/4 : ARG TEST
 ---> Running in 4130b437fd93
Removing intermediate container 4130b437fd93
 ---> a31b0f8a81ff
Step 3/4 : ENV TEST=${TEST:foo}
failed to process "${TEST:foo}": unsupported modifier (f) in substitution
```

Why is this not working? The error sounds like a complete misunderstanding between me and my docker engine.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Engine: Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `-`, it should be:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG TEST
ENV TEST=${TEST:-foo}
```